# how to declare variables during run time in c

Tags: c, variables, runtime

I am about to start a project of something like simple calculator completely in c and I was wondering how would I allow the user to create variables during the run time of the program, this variable could be a number or complex number or even a matrix or a 
one approach was to store the type of the variable, its name and its size and value in a temporary text file and retrieve it whenever needed, is there any better approach. I hope if I could declare real variables during runtime in c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you are going to need three basic modules:

N.B. I haven't had the time to actually compile these examples, hopefully I didn't make too many mistakes.

1. Parser.  This module takes a user entered input, tokenizes it and insures that the entered expression conforms to the grammer.
2. Interpreter. This module takes the output of the parser and preforms the computation.
3. Environment. This module manages the state of the computation.

Lets start with the environment, here is what we need (or at least what I would implement).  First here are the design considerations the I would use for the environment:

1. We will only deal with variables
2. We will only allow 300 variables
3. All variables will have global scope
4. Rebinding a variable will overwrite the old binding

Now, lets define the following structure:

```
typedef struct st
{
     char*   tokenName;
     int     type;
     union
     {
         int      iVal;
         float    fVal;
     } val;
 }  tableEntry, * ptableEntry;

 tableEntry    symbolTable[300];
```

and now for some functions:

a. init(tableEntry*) -- this function initialized the environment, i.e. sets all values in the symbol table to some, predefined empty state.

b. addValue(tableEntry*, name, value) -- this function takes a pointer to the environment and adds a new entry to the environment.

c. int lookupValue(tableEntry*, name) -- this function takes a pointer to the environment and sees if the token name has been defined in it.  Already, we see a problem, we are allowing for both integers and floating point numbers but would like a single lookup functions, so we probably need some sort of variant type or figure out some way to return different types.

d. updateValue(tableEntry*, name, value) -- this function takes a pointer to the environment and updates an existing value.  This raises an unaddressed specification, what should updateValue do if the token is not found?  Personally I would just add the value, but it up to you as the designer of the calculator on what to do.

This should do for a start for the environment.

Now lets turn to the interpreter for a bit.  For this let suppose that the parser emits the abstract syntax tree in prefix form.  For example:

the statement x=3 would be emitted as `= x 3`
the statement z = 4 + 5 would be emitted as `= z + 4 5`

OK, the trick here is we don't really emit `3`, but rather a token that contains more information about what is being passed around.

A possible implementation of a token might be:

```
typedef struct tok
{
    int tokType;
    char* tokVal;
} token, * ptoken;
```

Also lets have the following enumeration:

```
enum {EMPTY=0, ID, VAL, EQ, PLUS, SUB, MULT, DIV, LPAREN, RPAREN};
```

so, with this the simplified statement `= x 3`, would actually be the following 
structures:

```
{EQ, null} {ID, "x"} {VAL, "3"}
```

OK, so the interpreter in pseudo-code would look like (assuming that the above is presented to the interpreter as a list).

```
  while list not empty
  token <-- head(list)   /* this returns the first token as well as removing it from the list */
  switch (token.tokType)
  {
       ....

       case EQ:         /* handling assignment */
         token <--- head(list)
         name = token.name

         token <--- head(list)
         val = atoi(token.tokVal)

         addValue(env*, name, val);

         break;

      case ID:
         name = token.name

         val = lookupValue(env*, name)

      ....
  }
```

Please, be advise that the actual format of the above code will in all probability need to be modified to deal with other constructs, it is just a notional example!

Now it's your turn -- take a stab and show us what you've come up with.

Later 
T.

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare new variables at runtime in C as such.

For what you want you could make a list of structs for each type you want to support. Each struct then contains the name of the variable and its value. Declaring a variable will add a new struct to the list.

Comment: what doy you mean by lists ? linked lists

Comment: A linked list is one of the many options to implement a list. Pick whatever implementation you know by heart or already have code for. The simplest implementation is to use a fixed size array with a current index. But then the amount of variables is limited and you're wasting memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you were thinking about an interaction with you calculator that might look something like this:

```
    > myCalc
    mc>  x=5
    mc>  5
    mc>  3*x
    mc>  15
    mc> quit
    >
```

Where `myCalc` is the name of your program, and the `mc>`prompt shows interaction with the calculator, where the use enters a statement and the calculator displays the result of the statement.

Now, consider the first statement `x=5`, we need to parse it and determine if it is a valid according to the grammar you are using.  Assuming it is, you then need to evaluate the statement, which for sake of discussion has 
the abstract syntax tree (AST) `ASMT(x,VAL(5))`.  ASMT and VAL are notional operators.

Now, I would take this as adding a new binding for x into the current environment.  Exactly how this environment looks depends on what you are willing to allow, so for now lets assume you are just allowing variable assignment.  A simple associative array would work here, where the key is the variable name and the data would be the value.

Now consider the next statement `3*x`, after parsing we can assume the AST for the expression is `TIMES(3, ID(x))`.  Now on evaluation of this, or interpreter would first need to handle the `ID(x)` part which  would be looking up the value of `x` in the environment, which is 5.

After the above, the AST would look like `TIMES(3,5)` which would be directly evaluated as 15.

N.B.  I am being fairly loose with what how AST would be represented and how it would be evaluated by the interpreter.  I'm trying to give a flavour of what to do, not full low-level implementation details.

hope this helps (a bit),
T

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want could you please add little more explanation

Comment: OK, I've added a skeleton answer below for ya.  I'll try and add some more for you tomorrow (after sleep).